# How can I override the (host-side) C++ compiler CMake uses for CUDA target?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, buildconfiguration

I'm using a CUDA version which does not support the GCC version installed on my system (my GCC is too new). I'm trying to build a repository which uses CMake for build configuration.

I know how to override the C++ compiler, traditionally:

```
export CXX=/path/to/other/compiler-binary
```

and CMake picks this up. I can also use `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. However, neither of these options work when compiling CUDA host-side code: CMake still has CUDA try to use my default GCC version on my system.

How can I tell it to use the alternative C++ compiler for CUDA?

Additional info:

- CMake 3.22.1
- On Devuan GNU/Linux Chimaera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake will *not* (for now) default to using your `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` as the C++ compiler for CUDA host-side code; there's a different setting for that. Run your build configuration like so:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-9
```

(replace the path with to your chosen C++ compiler of course)